# Batch count all files but exclude those in a specific folder

Tags: batch-file

So I'm going to count files in a directory including all subfolders and get a output as a number of how many files it found within the directory. The problem is I want to exclude all the folders that has the name `error`. Those files within that folder I do not want to be counted.

***Simply...***

```
for /r "\\server\share\folderA" %%G in (*.*) do (
set /A count=count + 1
)    
echo %count%
```

Under folderA there are plenty of subfolders that I'm counting, but also the "error" folders that I do not want to count.

***So I'm trying the following...***

Create a temp file called `exclude.txt` and type `error` to that file

```
if not exist "c:\temp" mkdir "c:\temp" 2>nul
if not exist c:\temp\exclude mkdir c:\temp\exclude 2>nul
echo error> %excludefolder%\exclude.txt
```

Now I want to combine this somehow. Basically do something like this...

```
for /r "\\server\share\folderA" %%G in (*.*) EXCLUDE: c:\temp\exclude\exclude.txt do (
set /A count=count + 1
)
```

But I'm aware this will not work and I'm not sure how to work it out. Does anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DIR /S /B /A-D` to iterate all files. The output includes the full path to each file.

Pipe that result to `FINDSTR /L /I /V "\\error\\` to filter out paths that contain `\error\`. This will also exclude any folders within an `error` folder. The search could be modified to exclude only 'error' but include children of 'error'.

Pipe that result to `FIND /C /V ""` to count the number of files (lines).

```
dir /s /b /a-d | findstr /liv "\\error\\" | find /c /v ""
```

The above will simply display the count.

If you want to capture the count in a variable, then use FOR /F to parse the output of the above command. Unquoted poison characters like `|` must be escaped when used in FOR /F.

```
@echo off
for /f %%N in ('dir /s /b /a-d^|findstr /liv "\\error\\"^|find /c /v ""') do set count=%%N
echo count=%count%
```

Comment: Thanks for an great answer @dbenham. This seems to do the job. Just for the record, can I exclude more folders by using this setup? For example if I could add `"\\error\\" "\\anotherfolder\\"` after `/liv`?

Comment: @MadsTheMan - Almost like that. You would put all the exclusion folders in one string, delimited by spaces: `findstr /liv "\\error\\ \\anotherFolder\\"`. If the folder name includes spaces, then you would need multiple \C:string options: `findstr /iv /c:"\\error\\" /c:"\\another folder\\"`. Read the built in help using `help findstr` or `findstr /?`. Also, you might be interested in reading about undocumented features at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053

Comment: Thanks for the input, just perfect. And that link - gold value.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude from count the folder containing the string "error" :

```
@echo off
set count=0

for /r "\\server\share\folderA" %%a in (*.*) do (
  echo %%~pa | find /i "error" || set /A count+=1
)    
echo %count%
```

It's a good way if you sure that you just have **ONE** *Error folder*. If you have another folder containing the string "error" it will be excluded too from count.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Worked like a charm on smaller folders, but when I tried it in a folder with 10k + files it went super slow. I have no idéa why, but I did learn something anywho. Again, thanks!

Comment: This method is slow because: **1.** It use a pipe that requires to run _two copies_ of `cmd.exe` (a 400 KB size file), one for each side of the pipe. **2.** It additionally run `find.exe`, a  16 KB size file. And the main reason: **3.** It execute previous steps _one time for each file name_! A faster approach would be to check if the name contain the search word using just internal commands: `set "name=%%~Pa" & if "!name:error=!" equ "%%~Pa" set /A count+=1`. If you want to test this method, don't forget to include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` line at beginning of the program.

Comment: @aacini Thanks for your explanation, I needed that. I'm going to test it and see how it works. :)